# How to cover code for rest Apex Class?

Tags: unit-test

I am writing test class for Rest service post method.i am covering code please help to cover code for this class.
Test Class:

```
@istest
public class Leadconvert_Test {
    testmethod static void postlead(){
     Leadconvert.post('test','user','test@user.com','welcome');
        lead l = new lead();
        l.firstname = 'test';
        l.lastname = 'user';
        l.email = 'test@user.com';
        l.company = 'welcome';
        insert l;
        account a = new account();
        a.name = 'welcome';
        insert a;
        contact c = new contact();
        c.firstname = 'test';
        c.lastname = 'user';
        c.email = 'test@user.com';
        c.accountid = a.id;
        insert c;     
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any data in lead list ?

Comment: Also specify which error you are facing.

Comment: Thank you for responding..yes if lead exist with related parameters that lead will have in lead list.

Comment: i am not facing any error but code not covering 7% only covering help me how to cover code

Answer (score 0):

I would go through the trailhead apex rest callouts module. It would be a good idea to add some mock HTML callouts. Follow the link below should take you to the trailhead module.

[Apex REST Callouts Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)